# jQuery data missing from only in local development environment

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose there is a web application that has the following `application.js`.

```
$(function () {
  $('#element').data('hello', 'itsme');
});
```

The web application is deployed, and from browser console doing

```
$('#element').data('hello')
```

returns `itsme` as expected.

However, from local development environment (i.e. http://localhost.com/example), doing the exactly the same thing returns `undefined`.

Is there something I am missing about jQuery data?

---

The exact situation:
This is my deployed module: https://togetherjs.com/examples/youtube/
From console, you can get the player object like below

```
var f = $('iframe')[0];
var player = $(f).data('togetherjs-player')
```

Doing exactly the same thing in local development environment, I get `player == undefined`.
What could be a possible reason?

Comment: Make sure your code in in DOM ready .

Comment: whether the iframe source is in the same domain as in the local page... or you are having a different domain content in the iframe

Comment: Can you explain it more @ArunPJohny? I think that might be a problem. BTW the local environment is the exact copy of the entire website, not just the javascript modules.

Comment: When I console out the variable f ( in your example above ), I see the iframe, but there is no data attribute given to it.

Comment: Interesting.. Firefox console seems to return `undefined` as well.

Comment: @jamesemanon try with latest Chrome?

Comment: I am using firefox 26.0